# why i got ‘replace’ was not declared in this scope error?

Tags: c++

I wanna to use replace for my code to detect palindrome, and this is part of it

```
cout<<isPalindrome("Won't I panic in a pit now?")<<endl;

bool PalindromeFinder::isPalindrome(string input){

    char chars[] = {' ' , '\'' , '?' , '!' , ','};

    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        replace(input.begin(), input.end(), chars[i], '\0');


    }
```

it give me the proper result which is wontipanicinapitnow

but when when i run the function it gave me ‘replace’ was not declared in this scope. any suggestion?

Comment: `i<input.length()` in the for loop is incorrect.  Length of `chars[]` should be used.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't `#include <algorithm>`, and you didn't write `std::replace`.

The documentation is your friend.

Comment: Read The Friendly Manual

Comment: sorry for the uncompleted code, i type using namespace std; on the top. so every time i use replace i should add #include <algorithm> in the header?

Comment: also do i have to place input in front of the replace? like input.replace(); but every time add it, it doesn't gave the right output

Comment: Which book are you using, @QifengSun? The good ones explain this early on. (I didn't say to write `input.replace()`, did I?)

Comment: Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++: Vectors and Arrays Bjarne Stroustrup By Bjarne Stroustrup May 29, 2014